# What is the meaning of 有本事？

Tags: meaning

Context 1: - 看我不打死你 - 你打呀！**有本事**你就打呀！

Context 2: 傅文佩！你别躲在里面不出声！我知道你在家。你**有本事**抢男人，怎么**没本事**开门啊？开门！

Context 3: 怎么着？**有本事**你再回去你哥哥的公会啊？

Context 4: **有本事**你开开呀？你敢开我就敢跳！

The literal meaning is having the ability to do something, but this word seems to be used often in arguments, and its most relevant expression in english is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"本事" is ability or skill.

However, "没本事开门" does not literal mean that she "does not have the ability to open the door". Considering the context, it is more like she "does not have other abilities (social power, combat power?) to make her courageous enough to open the door" (for the aggressive visitor), i.e., she "dares not open the door".

Considering the phrase is often used in sentences like somebody "有本事" do something "呀": This sentence is an aggressive taunt or provocation, so a more relative English expression is "dare".

有本事你就打呀！ -- Hit me if you dare!

Answer (score 1):

> 1. '有本事' (have the ability) is used literally in this sentence:

"有本事抢男人，怎么没本事开门啊？" (You have the ability to grab other women's man, why don't you have the ability to open the door?)

*She does have the ability to grab other women's man and she did. At least the speaker think so.*

> 2. '有本事' (have the ability) is used sarcastically (a dare, or a rhetorical question/ statement) in the following sentences:

有本事你就打呀！(Hit me if you have the ability) --> Meaning: "I bet you don't have it" (because you wouldn't dare) or (because you are not fast enough)

有本事你开门呀！(Open the door if you have the ability) --> Meaning: "I say you don't have the ability" (because you wouldn't dare) or (because you are not physically strong enough)

Notice: an 'if' (如果) is implied in the two examples above

(如果)有本事你就打呀

(如果)有本事你开门呀

Answer (score 1):

有本事 here means ***being capable of dealing with the consequences(if one does something)***.  E. g.  有本事你就打呀 means *if you can deal with the consequence, then you go ahead to hit.*

Basically, the phrase is used to ***challenge one's boldness***.

Answer (score 1):

有句话叫"艺高人胆大"，通常来说，有本事的人（艺高者）理应胆子也大。所以这句话可以理解为，"如果你够大胆……）

如果用"有本事"的本义来翻译来英语，这句话就不好理解了。不如简单点翻译成

```
If you dare, just hit me. (Let's see the consequence.)
```